# A Story that Feels Very 50s Heinlein About A Forced to Retire Rocket Man

Tags: story-identification

He's sitting in the space port longing to go back. Some current members of the space force kid him for being too old at 19 or 20.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Any idea where or when you read this?

Comment: "Age of Retirement" by Hal Lynch was a short story with the narrator bitterly resenting the fact that he'd have to retire from the Space Patrol when he reached age 16. So that *isn't* the same story you're thinking of, because the main character still had a couple of years to go before he'd be forced out the door on the grounds that he must be getting too mature to really be excited about that type of work.

Comment: @user14111 Wasn't planning to. I saw your comment about *Galactic Empires, Vol. 1* (which is where I first encountered that story), but I think that's a thin basis for posting an "Answer" by mentioning a story which has a different plot from what the OP was describing. To me, "I don't want to have to retire in a few more years" is a different plot from "I hate the fact that people are teasing me because I already did retire." It's always *possible* that Techteacher314 will follow your link and then say that *was* the right story after all, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.

Comment: @user14111: FWIW, it seems like a close enough answer to me to be worth a partial answer, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"The Old Man" by Robert Silverberg.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64938

You can see it here, albeit in rather fragmented form.
https://archive.org/stream/Imagination_v08n02_1957-04_Gorgon776/Imagination_v08n02_1957-04_Gorgon776_djvu.txt

Comment: Hi and welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. Thank you for your answer. Your answer currently consists mainly of links; you can significantly improve it by adding some of the information found at this links into your answer. Do you know anything more about Silberberg's story?